# Common scale for multiple plots

Tags: plotting, scaling

I want to plot an orthographic (as in "drafting" with top, side, and front view) of a complex sinusoid in time.  Here's my attempt:

```
a = -0.1
b = 1.0
\[Nu] = 1.0
\[Eta] = .1*2*\[Pi]
A = 1.0
f[t_] := A*Sin[2*\[Pi]*\[Nu]*t + \[Eta]]
p1 := PolarPlot[A, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
p2 := DiscretePlot[f[t], {t, a, b, 0.015}, PlotStyle -> Red]
p3 := Rotate[p2, 3 \[Pi]/2]
GraphicsGrid[{{p1, p2}, {p3}}]
```

But, the 3 views have different scale factors.  Is there a way to require a common scale, or is there a better approach?  Thx, Dave

Comment: Try adding `AspectRatio -> Automatic` to p2.

Comment: Thanks!  AspectRatio->Automatic worked well.  However, when I change image size either by click & drag or Show ImageSize->Large, the rotated plot doesn't change size.  Any idea why and how to control its scale?

Comment: On closer look, AspectRatio->Automatic "almost" did the trick.  What I want is the ability to make the axes of 2 different plot on the same graphic to be the same length:  I want control over scale, position, and rotation of 3 plots in the same graphic.  Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
a = -0.1;
b = 1.0;
\[Nu] = 1.0;
\[Eta] = .1*2*\[Pi];
A = 1.0;
f[t_] := A*Sin[2*\[Pi]*\[Nu]*t + \[Eta]];
p2 = DiscretePlot[f[t], {t, a, b, 0.015}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{-.2, 1}, {-1, 1}}];

PolarPlot[A, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[-1, 1, .2], Range[-1, 1, .2]},
 Epilog -> {Inset[p2, {1.4, 0}, {0, 0}, Scaled[{1, .5}]],
   Inset[p2, {0, -1.4}, {0, 0}, Scaled[{1, .5}], {0, -1}]},
 PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 1.5}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I feel this is overly "tricky" to get everything on the same axes. It might be better to do it somehow with `Show`, but I haven't figured it out.

Comment: Thanks MelaGo, I

Comment: ... I agree it seems like there should be a "Show" approach.  I'll keep an eye open for it...

Answer (score 2):

There must be a more natural way to have common scales but here is one way that requires the tweaking of the `ImageSize` values.  The main "fix" to get the figures to line up is to use a negative `Spacings` in `GraphicsGrid`.

```
a = -0.1
b = 1.0
ν = 1.0
η = .1*2*π
A = 1.0
f[t_] := A*Sin[2*π*ν*t + η]
p1 = PolarPlot[A, {t, 0, 2 π}, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 510];
p2 = DiscretePlot[f[t], {t, a, b, 0.015}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-0.3, 1}, {-1, 1}}, ImageSize -> 500];
p3 = Rotate[p2, 3 π/2];
GraphicsGrid[{{p1, p2}, {p3}}, Spacings -> -10]
```

[image: Plots at same scale]

When the `ImageSize` is chosen to be the same for both `p1` and `p2`, then the plots don't quite line up properly.  Using 510 and 500 (or 305 and 300) seems have the plots line up reasonably.

Comment: Yes, thanks JimB, for the benefit of your insight. I'm disappointed there's not a more natural way to do this, but at least I can achieve my objective.